# Are there people that have played at 2000 OTB to master level by focusing on playing exclusively blitz rated games online?

Tags: online-chess, blitz, otb-chess

Are there chess players for example, that have gotten to say, Lichess 2700+ Blitz online without ever playing OTB and then as soon as they started OTB, they were playing at a 2000 to master level?

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but I am convinced the answer is: no. Chess is not poker. Not quite yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if there's anyone who has reached from 2000 OTB rating to master level by just playing blitz online. But there's an Indian player (**V. Pranav**) who used to play a lot of online blitz on [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/stats/live/blitz/vi_pranav). He was around `2300` in 2020 October and right now has around 2900 blitz rating. His highest being 3000.

After the lockdown got over in India, he started playing a few OTBs and managed to get his IM title. Earlier in 2020, he was around 2250 in classical and now he is almost 2500. You can check this out [here](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/25060783/chart).

EDIT:

V. Pranav became India's 75th GM on 8th August 2022.

Comment: Caveat:  V. Pranav was born in 2006.  There may be an age-related confounding factor based on time available, life responsibilities, and possibly brain physiology.  (though I agree some players learn more through playing than others, i.e. Nakamura)

Comment: A player called skrobic dragan used to have 2700+ in playchess 11-12 years ago while being fide unrated. But he must have played some kind of otb

Comment: Same with yaacov norowitz.